# Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, /snap/pycharm-professional/127/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in, -i]

Tags: django, linux, python-3.x, bash, pycharm

My Pycharm was working perfectly fine all of a sudden I see the below error message. I have pycharm professional version

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue

```
Cannot open Local Terminal

Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, /snap/pycharm-professional/127/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in, -i] in /home/path-to-my-project

See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in Files) for the details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the log files it gave the below details. I had Ubuntu running on my host Windows Machine. Restarting both the host and the guest. resolved the issue. Reminds me of the movie. Skyscraper with Dwane Johnson

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 138412032 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
```